# extracting power from polynomials

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int num,k,p,w;
    char parts[30];
    char power[30];
    scanf("%s",parts);
    int count=strlen(parts);
    for(w=0;w<count;w++){
            if(parts[w]=='^')
                num=w;
        }
        if(isdigit(num)) {
        for(k=num+1 ; k<count ;k++)
            strcat(power,parts[k]);
        }
        else{
        strcpy(power,'1');
        }

        p=atoi(power);
        printf(" the power is : %d\n",p);
}
```

.. can any one tell me what's wrong here ??
i keep running the code but nothing happens ... but it looks alright to me

Comment: input example :   5x^4

Comment: What is target to do? :/

Comment: The variable `w` is the *index*  into the `parts` array. Doing `num = w` will assign this *index* to the variable `num` not the actual digit in the string.

Comment: If input doesn't contain a `'^'`, then your code exhibits Undefined Behavior as `num` is not initialized here-->`if(isdigit(num))`. If the input *does* contain a `'^'`, then the `if` will be true.

Comment: You surely would have got warnings on compiling your code, right?

Comment: Also, when you fix that problem, you have another and more serious problem, namely [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)! Local variables, like the array `power`, are not initialized, their contents is *indeterminate*, and using them uninitialized leads to said undefined behavior. The problem you have is that `strcat` reads the contents of the `power` array to find the end of the string, but since it's contents is indeterminate (and in reality seemingly random) the function may find a string terminator long after the array ends.

Comment: Furthermore, the `strcat` function concatenates two *strings*, and you're passing a single character as the second argument which will first of all make the compiler scream at you for being stupid, then it will not work as expected as that single character will be used as a *pointer*.

Comment: Thank you all for your notes

Comment: Please structure your question when posting here. What is your error, what is it that you don't understand ... We aren't mind readers.

Comment: `sscanf(parts, "%dx^%d", &k, &p);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:

1. If the user enters something that doesn't contain a `'^'`, then your code exhibits [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as num is not initialized here

   ```
   if(isdigit(num))
   ```

   If the input does contain a `'^'`, then the `if` will be true.
2. Here:

   ```
   strcat(power,parts[k]);
   ```

   `strcat` finds the NUL-terminator in its first argument and overwrites its second argument from that position. But `power` isn't initialized! So, this also invokes [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Furthermore, `parts[k]` is a `char`, but `strcat` expects both its arguments to be NUL-terminated and **be of type `const char*`**.
   Initialize `power by using

   ```
   char power[30]={0};
   ```

   and change the `strcat` to

   ```
   strcat(power,&parts[k]);
   ```
3. The same problem is seen here too:

   ```
   strcpy(power,'1');
   ```

   Change it to

   ```
   strcpy(power,"1");
   ```

   to fix it. The double quotes make the string literal of type `const char*` which is `\0` terminated
4. Here:

   ```
   scanf("%s",parts);
   ```

   The user *could* enter some string more than 29 characters long(+1 for the `\0` terminator). This would also cause [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Fix it by limiting the number of characters to be scanned by using

   ```
   scanf("%29s",parts);
   ```

   The `scanf` will scan at most 29 characters(+1 for the `\0` terminator) from the standard input stream when this is done.

Comment: it worked just fine ... and i adjusted the < isdigit(num) >  to < parts[num]=='^' >

Comment: uummmm ... something goes wrong when the power has more than one digit

Comment: @EliasKhoury , Did you do everything mentioned in my answer? BTW, accept an answer if it helped by pressing the green checkmark(tick mark) beside them. By doing so, you, as well as the answerer can earn reputation.

Comment: @EliasKhoury , I don't know what is wrong. You can ask a new question about it.

Comment: mmmm i'll try solving it on my own ... if i can't i'll ask a new question

Comment: @EliasKhoury . In that case, please make sure that you include whatever you've tried in the question, if you post one.